# How do I update my model object before a create/update?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

It's me the big rails newbie. I have another problem.

This is my partial for _care_point.html.erb

```
<div id='<%=dom_id(care_point) %>' class='draggable node_chin'>
  <div id=<%="node_#{care_point.id}" %> class='node'><%= care_point.body %>
  </div>
  <textarea class='node_input'><%= care_point.body %></textarea>
  <%= link_to 'Close', [care_map, care_point], :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => 'close' %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', [care_map, care_point], :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'delete' %>
</div>
```

When I click the Close link the request is sent to the server as expected. All the fields are null though. How do I make sure that my model object is kept updated before it is sent to the server? Do I have to use the form functionality or can I just update it with Javascript somehow?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason not to use forms. Just enclose your fields into a form and add a submit button.

```
<%= form_for [care_map, care_point], :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit "Close" %>
<% end %>
```

If you really want Close link instead of button, you can use javascript to override it's click event and send a form via Ajax.

Comment: How would I send a form via Ajax? :)